# Looking for a way to copy missing files from one directory to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two directory:

1. `/A` which contains thousands of data files
2. `/A_BKP` which has to contains backup of `/A` directory

I am looking for a way to copy the files which have not been copied as a part of backup from `/A` to `/A_BKP`.

A small dataset from `/A` directory -

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu   6434570 Jun  5 14:11 ACCOUNT_1622902306293.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu   2891626 Jun  5 14:11 PRODUCT_1622902306293.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu  56736348 Jun  5 14:11 EXECUTION_1622902306293.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu  30209979 Jun  5 14:11 ORDER_VERSION_1622902306293.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu       114 Jun  5 14:11 1622902306293.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu   3905808 Jun  5 14:31 ACCOUNT_1622903506439.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu   1712506 Jun  5 14:31 PRODUCT_1622903506439.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu  55188313 Jun  5 14:31 EXECUTION_1622903506439.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu  26857690 Jun  5 14:31 ORDER_VERSION_1622903506439.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu       114 Jun  5 14:31 1622903506439.DAT
```

But the `/A_BKP` has already

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu  26857690 Jun  5 14:31 ORDER_VERSION_1622903506439.DAT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testu testu       114 Jun  5 14:31 1622903506439.DAT
```

So want to just copy only those which are missing.

Comment: have you tried `rsync` ? Also GNU `cp(1)` has the `-u` flag.

Comment: Reiterating @Jetchisel's comment, and adding `rsnapshot` as a much better backup mechanism (which also uses rsync under the covers). And, with that, this likely belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--no-clobber` (or `-n`) option:

```sh
cp -t /A_BKP --no-clobber /A/*
```

If you get an "argument list too long" error, you might have to do

```sh
find /A -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print 0 \
| xargs -0 cp -n -t /A_BKP
```

---

`-n` prevents copying if the destination file exists. As @Jetchisel comments, use `-u` to *update* the destination file if the source file is newer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over files, check if exists. `||` is for `test` returning `false`, then it will copy.

```
for file in /A/*.DAT; test -f /A_BKP/`basename $file` || cp $file /A/BKP/; done
```